# If the letters T*(RBJBR)=VPLNT each represented a unique digit, and "RBJBR" was a five digit number, what are possible values for the letters?

Tags: puzzle

If the letters T*(RBJBR)=VPLNT each represented a unique digit, and "RBJBR" was a five digit number, what are possible values for the letters? (Or ONE possible value.)

Can we do this in a way that can be done on paper without "guessing and plugging numbers" (or computers, for that matter)?

Got this question as a math challenge from a club, not sure how do go about it.

Comment: This is not so much "cryptography" as it is a "cryptarithm". It's a puzzle.

Comment: @BrettFrankel I have no idea what that means. New here. :D
Apologies about the tag misplacement, I'm not sure where I should put it.

Comment: If you ask a question and somebody solves it to your satisfaction, you can click the check mark underneath the arrows. The answerer will be awarded with a few reputation points, and other users will see that you are in need of a solution.

Comment: Whoops, now I should go back through my questions and click those marks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start...

If you check the last digit, you'll see that $T*R$ ends in $T$. Also, by looking at the first digit, $T*R$ is at most $9$, otherwise the right side has $6$ digits.

Then $T*R=T$ which means that either $T=0$ (not possible) or $R=1$. Thus $R=1$.

$T*(1BJB1)=VPLNT$

Comment: which reduces the problem to $T\cdot(1BJB)=VPLN$.